# How to read input on startup of the program?

Tags: input, startup, pascal

I have a problem with reading input directly at the start of the program – I would like to start a program like:

```
program.exe file.txt
```

so my `program.exe` will start and find, that it should load `file.txt` and do something with it (code for doing something I already have)..

Writing:

```
read(FileName);
```

on the first line of my main program is not working – the program is still waiting for input after the start.

Comment: You can always redirect input from file to your console application by running it with `program.exe < file.txt` in the console (will work in both Linux and Windows).

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you @NikolayKostov , I can use this as well.

Comment: Since this is the answer I will write it as an answer.

Comment: I just found out the right way ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is, what I actually wanted to do: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Command_line_parameters_and_environment_variables

So for input:

```
program.exe file.txt
```

the program, which resolve which file I should open will be:

```
program FindGivenFileName;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

var FileName: string;

begin
  FileName := ParamStr(1);
  {next parts of code are missing here, but working}
end.
```

In the array of `ParamStr`, 0 is name of the program and numbers higher are paramaters – the first parameter is `ParamStr(1)`, second is `ParamStr(2)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can always redirect input from file to your console application by running it with:

```
program.exe < file.txt
```

in the console (will work in both Linux and Windows).